# Can we protect against SQL-injection by writing Javascript code correctly? how?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, security, sql-injection

I am trying to understand abit more of the security implication of SQL injection and was unsure about this and I cant find anything useful on the web.

Can we protect against SQL-injection by writing Javascript code correctly? How?

Cheers

Comment: This question is really far too broad. Stackoverflow is great for getting answers to specific questions about coding problems and curiosities.

Comment: JavaScript and SQL have nothing to do with each other.  What if I turn off JavaScript?  Or what if I open my console and do `curl --data "username='); DROP TABLE users; --" http://YourSite.com`?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you reconsider your current method of asking questions.  You've had one question closed, two more than will be imminently closed, and two more beyond that with close votes as well.  Your questions are open-ended and chatty, and are not a good fit for SO.  If you get too many questions closed in a row, you may incur an automatic question ban.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never try and prevent SQL injection solely by JavaScript.  What happens if I turn JavaScript off? Your validation fails instantly.  What happens if I modify your JS and remove the keywords you are preventing me from injecting?

Always validate it against the server.

Answer (score 1):

Its not about writing JavaScript correctly.

Its about ensuring on the server side that you do not use user input text directly in your queries. Its also about making sure you use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead of direct full queries.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, unless you happen to run your SQL queries directly in JS. Your **last** part of the chain to the query should be doing the parametrization and validation. The reason for this is pretty simple: JS can be disabled in-browser, rendering your sanitization useless.

SQL injection (first-order) can be prevented safely using parametrization alone. This is your true protection vector - no amount of in-text sanitization can entirely reduce the risk.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript on client side is always exposed to the user. Turning off Javascript will easily defeat it. Validations should always be placed both on client side and on server side, to ensure complete protection.